# Parse ajax response properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I get data from the server with Ajax.

Data returned (from firebug):

```
{"users":[{"name":"some name", "age":17},{"name":"some name2", "age":25}]}
```

When I try

```
$.post('server.php', function(data){
    var users = eval(data).users;
    alert(users[0].name);
});
```

I get on firebug:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

Any help?

Comment: You tried without the eval? (Which is evil and shouldn't be used anyway!) Just `data.users[0].name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to surround the json string with brackets

```
$.post('server.php', function(data){
    var users = eval('('+data+')').users;
    alert(users[0].name);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPYgF/)

Comment: I definitely don't recommend this. Just pass `"json"` as the last argument and `data` will be an object.

Comment: both Prototype’s evalJSON and JQuery’s parseJSON use eval…

Comment: @skafandri jQuery's parseJSON will first try to use a native browser function, and if it doesn't exist, it'll make sure that the string is valid before parsing it. Check the jQuery source, and search for "parseJSON": http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

Comment: BAD SOLUTION TO ACCEPT! It works, but so does opening a window with a hammer.

Answer (score 10):

**Please do not use eval - it's [evil](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/)**

Instead, simply use a parameter of "json".

```
$.post('server.php', function(data) {
    alert(data.users[0].name);
}, "json");
```

If your headers are proper, you don't even need the json parameter, but it forces jQuery to want to receive and parse it as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

encode data in brackets with single quotes

```
 $.post('server.php', function(data){
        var users = eval('('+data+')');
        alert(users[0].name);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the point on `eval()` but maybe I don't know the function well...

With this works:

```
var data = {"users":[{"name":"some name", "age":17},{"name":"some name2", "age":25}]};
alert(data.users[0].name);
```

​You also may loop with:

```
$.each(data.users, function (i, user_obj){
    alert(user_obj.name);
});
```

Take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dx2hA/).

It's better to add the `dataType: "json"` to your ajax request so it's properly parsed.

Comment: You're using mootools instead of jQuery.

Comment: @AntonioLaguna The problem isn't mootools, as his jdfiddle doesn't use anything but native javascript. The problem is the fact that he's using a string instead of an object. This is the correct JS: http://jsfiddle.net/bEj5X/1/